# What is default timeout value of RestSharp RestClient?

Tags: http, timeout, restsharp, rest-client

Anybody aware of default timeout value of [RestSharp](https://github.com/restsharp/) RestClient ?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

RestSharp is using HttpWebRequest under the hood, which has a [default timeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout) of 100 seconds.

Answer (score 4):

At least some versions of RestSharp (I'm looking at 106.6.10) will use an explicitly set Timeout value when using the async requests, but do not provide a default.

This is because:

> The Timeout property has no effect on asynchronous requests made with the BeginGetResponse or BeginGetRequestStream method.

(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout?view=netframework-4.8#remarks)

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the **v107**  `RestSharp` stops using the legacy `HttpWebRequest` class, and uses well-known `HttpClient` instead. `Timeout` option now is obsolete and they recommend using `MaxTimeout` instead.

Regarding the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/developer/methods-auto/httpclient/httpclient-timeout-method):

> If you don't set a duration, then a default value is used. The default
> value is currently **100000 ms (100 seconds).**

In addition, if you want to change options there is the next syntax:

```
        var options = new RestClientOptions("https://api.myorg.com")
        {
            ThrowOnAnyError = true,
            MaxTimeout = 1000 // ms
        };

        var client = new RestClient(options);
```

Comment: Oh my god… it’s in milliseconds. Well I spent way too much time on that one... Tip: put 1 * 1000 to make it clear. Or add // ms

Comment: @Simon_Weaver, done (added `// ms` )